# Error using Git Push in RStudio

Tags: git, rstudio

I'm using git in Rstudio to push code to a github repository. This worked fine until a few days ago, now I get the following error when I click the push button:

> github --credentials get: github: command not found
>         0 [main] bash (7692) C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\usr\bin\bash.exe:
>   *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x12C7408/0x1307408. This problem is probably due to using
>   incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL. Search for cygwin1.dll using
>   the Windows Start->Find/Search facility and delete all but the most
>   recent version.  The most recent version *should* reside in
>   x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have installed the
>   cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you are unable to
>   find another cygwin DLL.
>         0 [main] bash 7164 fork: child -1 - forked process 7692 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11 C:/Program
>   Files/RStudio/bin/postback\rpostback-askpass: fork: retry: No child
>   processes
>         0 [main] bash (1180) C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\usr\bin\bash.exe:
>   *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x12C7408/0x13E7408. This problem is probably due to using
>   incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL. Search for cygwin1.dll using
>   the Windows Start->Find/Search facility and delete all but the most
>   recent version.  The most recent version *should* reside in
>   x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have installed the
>   cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you are unable to
>   find another cygwin DLL. 1022288 [main] bash 7164 fork: child -1 -
>   forked process 1180 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142,
>   errno 11 C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/postback\rpostback-askpass:
>   fork: retry: No child processes
>         1 [main] bash (2732) C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\usr\bin\bash.exe:
>   *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x12C7408/0x1197408. This problem is probably due to using
>   incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL. Search for cygwin1.dll using
>   the Windows Start->Find/Search facility and delete all but the most
>   recent version.  The most recent version *should* reside in
>   x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have installed the
>   cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you are unable to
>   find another cygwin DLL. 3053296 [main] bash 7164 fork: child -1 -
>   forked process 2732 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142,
>   errno 11 C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/postback\rpostback-askpass:
>   fork: retry: No child processes
>         0 [main] bash (476) C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\usr\bin\bash.exe:
>   *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x12C7408/0x10D7408. This problem is probably due to using
>   incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL. Search for cygwin1.dll using
>   the Windows Start->Find/Search facility and delete all but the most
>   recent version.  The most recent version *should* reside in
>   x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have installed the
>   cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you are unable to
>   find another cygwin DLL. 7084656 [main] bash 7164 fork: child -1 -
>   forked process 476 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142,
>   errno 11 C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/postback\rpostback-askpass:
>   fork: retry: No child processes
>         0 [main] bash (5424) C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\usr\bin\bash.exe:
>   *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x12C7408/0x1157408. This problem is probably due to using
>   incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL. Search for cygwin1.dll using
>   the Windows Start->Find/Search facility and delete all but the most
>   recent version.  The most recent version *should* reside in
>   x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have installed the
>   cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you are unable to
>   find another cygwin DLL. 15112190 [main] bash 7164 fork: child -1 -
>   forked process 5424 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142,
>   errno 11 C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/postback\rpostback-askpass:
>   fork: Resource temporarily unavailable error: unable to read askpass
>   response from 'rpostback-askpass'
>         0 [main] bash (9460) C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\usr\bin\bash.exe:
>   *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x12C7408/0x1327408. This problem is probably due to using
>   incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL. Search for cygwin1.dll using
>   the Windows Start->Find/Search facility and delete all but the most
>   recent version.  The most recent version *should* reside in
>   x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have installed the
>   cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you are unable to
>   find another cygwin DLL.
>         0 [main] bash 3908 fork: child -1 - forked process 9460 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11 bash: fork:
>   retry: No child processes
>         0 [main] bash (4036) C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\usr\bin\bash.exe:
>   *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x12C7408/0x1217408. This problem is probably due to using
>   incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL. Search for cygwin1.dll using
>   the Windows Start->Find/Search facility and delete all but the most
>   recent version.  The most recent version *should* reside in
>   x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have installed the
>   cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you are unable to
>   find another cygwin DLL. 1040452 [main] bash 3908 fork: child -1 -
>   forked process 4036 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142,
>   errno 11 bash: fork: retry: No child processes
>         1 [main] bash (4620) C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\usr\bin\bash.exe:
>   *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x12C7408/0x10A7408. This problem is probably due to using
>   incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL. Search for cygwin1.dll using
>   the Windows Start->Find/Search facility and delete all but the most
>   recent version.  The most recent version *should* reside in
>   x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have installed the
>   cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you are unable to
>   find another cygwin DLL. 3059723 [main] bash 3908 fork: child -1 -
>   forked process 4620 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142,
>   errno 11 bash: fork: retry: No child processes
>         1 [main] bash (6948) C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\usr\bin\bash.exe:
>   *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x12C7408/0x11C7408. This problem is probably due to using
>   incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL. Search for cygwin1.dll using
>   the Windows Start->Find/Search facility and delete all but the most
>   recent version.  The most recent version *should* reside in
>   x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have installed the
>   cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you are unable to
>   find another cygwin DLL. 7088954 [main] bash 3908 fork: child -1 -
>   forked process 6948 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142,
>   errno 11 bash: fork: retry: No child processes
>         0 [main] bash (3480) C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\usr\bin\bash.exe:
>   *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x12C7408/0x1117408. This problem is probably due to using
>   incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL. Search for cygwin1.dll using
>   the Windows Start->Find/Search facility and delete all but the most
>   recent version.  The most recent version *should* reside in
>   x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have installed the
>   cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you are unable to
>   find another cygwin DLL. 15113095 [main] bash 3908 fork: child -1 -
>   forked process 3480 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142,
>   errno 11 bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable error: failed to
>   execute prompt script (exit code 254) fatal: could not read Username
>   for 'https://github.com': No error

I don't know why it doesn't work anymore. How can I deal with this error?

Comment: Well, my guess would be that this problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL. Did you upgrade anything lately? Such as git or gnu?

Comment: I've installed some windows updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reinstallation of Git solved the problem.